# datetime.strptime strange behavior

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, strptime

I'm getting the following error on aws virtual machine running python 3.6.8, while on my laptop it works fine with python 3.6.1

```
   return datetime.strptime(date_str, self.date_format)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Fri, 23 Aug 2019 20:24:46 IDT' does not match format '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z'
```

What's wrong with the format that I'm using?

Comment: yup.. seems like this is the case only in the virtual machine. when I replace %Z with IDT in the format string then it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this discussion](https://bugs.python.org/issue22377) on the official Python bug tracker. Apparently `%Z` only supports `UTC`, `GMT` and the local time zone (as returned by `time.tzname`).

It's an interesting case, the [official Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) are misleading (to put it nicely):

> %Z
>   Time zone name (empty string if the object is naive).(empty), UTC, EST, CST

This is wrong. `%Z` will only recognise `EST`, `CST`, etc. **if they are the local timezone of the OS**.

**EDIT** Well, there is a note near the bottom of the page in the docs that says

> `%Z`
>   If `tzname(`) returns `None`, `%Z` is replaced by an empty string. Otherwise `%Z` is replaced by the returned value, which must be a string.

Still, not as clear as it could be.

To make it clear:

It works on your local machine because it uses IDT as its local timezone, which is not the case for the AWS remote machine.

Comment: The documentation is not misleading. That text tells you what *output* you'll get *when you use `datetime.strftime()`, so turning a `datetime` instance into a string*. A `datetime` instance has a [`datetime.tzname()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.tzname), which is what the note refers to. There is no direct mention of `%Z` when it comes to `datetime.strptime()` behaviour (note the `p` for *parsing*).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Fair enough, but would expect the docs of `strptime` to mention that `%Z` will violently break if it sees a non-local timezone name, especially since it does so with a confusing  error message (it says the format does not match, but it does)

Comment: The docs are certainly lacking in that respect. See https://bugs.python.org/issue22377 and https://bugs.python.org/issue22426. The implementation uses a [pure Python module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7//Lib/_strptime.py) so is fully debuggable if you are so inclined, just step into the `datetime.strptime()` call.

Answer (score 1):

```py
datetime.datetime.strptime("IDT", "%Z")
```

produces an error

```py
ValueError: time data 'IDT' does not match format '%Z'
```

as %Z does not support IDT (Israel Daylight Time).

The solution depend on what you're doing with the data next. If you use [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) and ignore the 'IDT' part of the date strings you're stripping the time from, then you can store then while recording the timezone.

```py
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("Fri, 23 Aug 2019 20:24:46", "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
print(dt)

2019-08-23 20:24:46
```

whereas

```py
import pytz
idt = pytz.timezone('Israel')
dt_idt = dt.astimezone(idt)
print(dt_idt)

2019-08-23 22:24:46+03:00
```

is more utile.