# Converting Datetime string with non-zero padded day

Tags: python, datetime, format, strptime

I am trying to convert a string to datetime object in python. Some examples of the string includes `"Fri Oct 20 2006 4:25pm EDT"` and `"Wed Nov 1 2006 4:47pm EST"` The problem seems to be that the day is not zero-padded which is why `datetime` does not pick up the format

I have also tried slicing it to convert the first 15 characters only but it seems that the non-zero padded dates are still a problem.

```
import datetime

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    datetime_list.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Time Stamp'],
                                                    '%a %b %d %Y %I:%M%p %Z'))
```

I hope to get a datetime object out that only shows the year, month and date.

Comment: `datetime.strptime()` doesn't care about zero-padding.

Comment: I'm putting my money that the problem is with `%Z`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633715/datetime-strptime-strange-behavior/57633812#57633812)

Comment: @DeepSpace: it is, I was looking for a dupe to close to.

Comment: As I state in my answer on the duplicate: you want to *compartimentalize the issue*, by parsing substrings. In your case, removing the timezone works: `datetime.datetime.strptime("Wed Nov 1 2006 4:47pm", '%a %b %d %Y %I:%M%p')` produces `datetime.datetime(2006, 11, 1, 16, 47)`.

Comment: If the timezone is important to you (e.g. when you have to deal with more than just EST / EDT), then you'll have to create your own mapping from timezone name to `datetime.timezone()` offsets, or use a library like [`pytz`](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) to supply timezones for known abbreviations or use the [`python-dateutil` package date parser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) to parse the strings and include a timezone (requires you define a `tzinfos` argument, see the documentation).

Comment: Otherwise, just lop off the timezone when parsing: `datetime_list.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Time Stamp'][:-4], '%a %b %d %Y %I:%M%p'))`